# JSON error (Parse error on line 1:)

Tags: php, mysql, json, parsing

hi guys i have a problem when trying to receive information from my site to my app
the code i used in server

```
<?php
   $con=mysqli_connect("myHost","user","pass","database") or die(mysql_error());
   $sql="SELECT * FROM table";
   $result = mysqli_query($con,$sql) or die("Invalid query: " . mysql_error());      
   while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
   {
   $output[]=$row;
   }
   mysqli_close($con);
   echo json_encode($output);
   ?>
```

also when i enter code page it give me a result like this

```
[{"id":"1","username":"user1","password":"pass1"},{"id":"2","username":"user2","password":"pass2"},{"id":"3","username":"user3","password":"pass3"}]
```

but when i test it in [JSONLint](http://jsonlint.org/) it give me an error

```
Parse error on line 1:
<html><body><scriptt
^
Expecting '{', '['
```

what i have to do ... please anyone can help me ... :(

Comment: before passing it in `$output` variable encode it now.

Comment: Why do you send HTML to JSONLint? Your JSON string is fine.

Comment: Make sure you have just copied the JSON not the HTML along with.

Comment: don't mix mysqli with mysql_*

Comment: Make sure you have copied the right string,its working fine,i have tested it

Comment: you added HTML as well i guess..you just need to pass json

Comment: It is good to look at what you are copying and pasting. You copy HTML code into JSONLInt and tell us about JSON problems :)

Comment: @aldrin27 i encode it before passing but not work :(

Comment: @caCtus how  to do that ??

Comment: @AbhikChakraborty and how to do that ??

Comment: @Drew it's just mysqli commands ...

Comment: it's just mix and match. it is wrong

Comment: guys how to remove the html from my code ?? i don't have any idea about this thing :(

Comment: How to do what? I copied you JSON string in JSONLint and it is fine. Please be more specific about what you want to do or show more code.

Comment: @caCtus yeah it's work by this way but when enter my link it does not work :(

Comment: Copy this line of code,and paste in `JsonLint`   "[{"id":"1","username":"user1","password":"pass1"},{"id":"2","username":"user2","password":"pass2"},{"id":"3","username":"user3","password":"pass3"}]"

Comment: Please show more code. You are displaying HTML, it does not appears by itself... Or you are copying it from a tool that adds HTML, not directly from the source code.

Comment: @AsimShahzad i don't want to copy it i need to enter my link that content the php code

Comment: @Anas this is a valid json. I checked it

Comment: @caCtus my php file on server include only this code: 
<?php
   $con=mysqli_connect("myHost","user","pass","database") or die(mysql_error());
   $sql="SELECT * FROM table";
   $result = mysqli_query($con,$sql) or die("Invalid query: " . mysql_error());      
   while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
   {
   $output[]=$row;
   }
   mysqli_close($con);
   echo json_encode($output);
   ?>

Comment: @Anas don't be too confused in `mysql` and `mysqli`

Comment: @aldrin27 i convert all mysql to mysqli but same problem ...

Comment: What's the result of `$output` when use `print_r($output);`?

Comment: @aldrin27 same error ...

Comment: guys copy this link to JSONLint ... it include the php code that i write it ...
http://anas.byethost14.com/demo3.php

Comment: The code you gave us in the question can't provide this output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to get it working. I think server was what was giving me the error, not the code. When I switched to using localhost it works now.